# How to print text into a tkinter window

Tags: python, database, tkinter

I have made some code which generates some NPC's and stores them into a database, when you run the code, the user is required to type/ respond to the question that is asked and then the information is printed to the console. How can I make it so that the user can type into an entry field on tkinter and it prints the response. I want to make a GUI instead of it being used in the console. Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import random

fnames = ["Moon", "Ash", "Deep", "Alive", "Snowdrop", "Panda", "Cyanide", "Try", "Apple", "Drip", "Economy", "Sly", "Rain", "Computer", "Cluttered", "Premium", "Laughable", "Mixed", "Questionable", "Voiceless","Sassy", "Slim", "Hurt", "Waste", "Puffy"]

snames = ["Man", "Died", "Idiot", "Hard", "Pig", "Tree", "Windy", "Bot", "Drop", "Cow", "Woman", "Designation", "Memory", "DM", "Outrigger", "Diploma", "Sink", "Science", "Handicap", "Attack", "Helmet", "Mechanic", "Guide", "Tendency"]

weapons = ["Sword", "Knife", "Dagger", "Pistol", "Machine gun", "Spoon", "Spork", "Fork", "Umbrella", "RPG", "Submachine gun", "Cactus", "Stick", "Bomb", "Laserlight", "Fist"]

def connect(char_db):
  conn = None
  try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect(char_db)

    conn.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NPC (fname text, sname text, age integer, weapon text)")

    conn.commit()

  except Error as e:
    print(e)
  finally:
    if conn:
      conn.close()


def NPC_Count():
  conn = None
  try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("chars.db")

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM NPC")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    return len(results)
  except Error as e:
    print("error retrieving record count")
  finally:
    if conn:
      conn.close()

def Generate(total):
  for i in range (total):
    print("generating",i+1, "of",total)
    try:
      conn = sqlite3.connect("chars.db")

      cursor = conn.cursor()

      cursor.execute("INSERT INTO NPC (fname, sname, age, weapon) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", (random.choice(fnames), random.choice(snames), str(random.randint(15,75)), random.choice(weapons)))
      conn.commit()
    except Error as e:
      print("Error insterting a value into the NPC table")
    finally:
      if conn:
        conn.close()

def NPC_Details():
  conn = None
  try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect("chars.db")

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM NPC")
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print(random.choice(results))
  except Error as e:
    print("error retrieving record count")
  finally:
    if conn:
      conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  connect(r"chars.db")
  count = NPC_Count()
  print("There are currently",count,"NPC's in the table")
  print("Type r for a random NPC or a number to generate more")
  choice = input("")
  if choice == "r":
    NPC_Details()
  else:
    Generate(int(choice))
```

Comment: well actually right now it would be almost like writing code in Your place so I suggest start looking at tutorials, there are many great out there (on youtube) and they are easy to understand for example this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQSEXcf6s2I&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV or You can take a look at this great documentation: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm other than that You have to show Your efforts on this You have to have created some code regarding Your issue (one reason being that otherwise You won't learn anything.) I have no  spac

Comment: If You have a specific problem You can ask that but not that we just code stuff for You especially if it such a broad spectrum (except maybe if someone is in good mood)

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

# specify size of window.
root.geometry("250x170")

Create text widget and specify size.
T = tk.Text(root, height = 5, width = 52)

# Create label
l = tk.Label(root, text = "Fact of the Day")
l.config(font =("Courier", 14))

Fact = """A man can be arrested in
Italy for wearing a skirt in public."""

# Create button for next text.
b1 = tk.Button(root, text = "Next", )

# Create an Exit button.
b2 = tk.Button(root, text = "Exit",
            command = root.destroy) 

l.pack()
T.pack()
b1.pack()
b2.pack()

# Insert The Fact.
T.insert(tk.END, Fact)

tk.mainloop()
```